# FFMPEG - Stream to RTMP output and save to MP4 at same time - with reconnect

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm trying to setup a pipeline where I can take an input and save to MP4 whilst at the same time streaming to an RTMP server.

So far I've been able to use a tee filter to achieve this and also using the onfail=ignore to make sure the pipeline stays up in the event of the RTMP/Recording failing.

Which is great!

However, I don't want the RTMP to just give up if it were to drop or be disconnected, I'd like it to keep attempting to reconnect and resume the stream.

I don't think FFMPEG has something like this, so I'd need to write it in a bash script or something that keeps restarting the process in the event of a drop.

I just have no idea how to achieve this!

Has anybody got any ideas or tackled this before?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fifo format, which can reconnect.

My working example:

```
-f fifo -fifo_format flv \
-drop_pkts_on_overflow 1 -attempt_recovery 1 -recover_any_error 1 \
rtmp://bla.bla/bla
```

Comment: Unfortunately, whilst this does kind of work, it seems to break HLS playback on the media server. Something about the meta data that it transmits gets broken when using a FIFO buffer.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the accepted answer, but:

In FFmpeg, an encoder auto-detects it's parameters based on selected output format. Here the output format is unknown (that's correct for formats like "fifo" and "tee") so the encoder won't have all parameters setup the same as if using "flv" output format.

For example: Wowza Streaming Engine will report an error while trying to publish that RTMP stream:

```
H264Utils.decodeAVCC : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
```

To overcome that you should add `-flags +global_header` option.
This should help for @Matt's problem.